# Importing sting arrays to integer from csv to Neo4j using Cypher

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and Cypher and I'm trying to import some data from csv that includes an array of IDs. I have the query below working but as Cypher defaults to strings, I've been unable to find the best way to convert the array of placeIDs to integers.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'http://localhost:11001/project-ca45d786-e360-4e3b-b4b4-eb8fe62a7b55/People-Gridv2.csv' AS row
CREATE (:People {peopleID: toInteger(row.peopleID), nickname: row.nickname, firstName: row.firstName, lastName: row.lastName, relationship: row.relationship, firstMemory: row.firstMemory, lastMemory: row.lastMemory, placeID: split(row.placeID,";")})
```

I hoped that I'd be able to do something like the following, but it doesn't work:

```
placeID: toInteger(split(row.placeID,";"))
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that would probably something like

```
placeID : REDUCE(array=[] , s IN split(row.placeID,";") | array+[toInteger(s)] )
```

to get an array of integers

example

```
with '123;456' as placeID
return REDUCE(array=[] , s IN split(placeID,";") | array+[toInteger(s)] )
```

will return

```
[123,456]
```

and even shorter :)

```
with '123;456' as placeID
return [s IN split(placeID,";") | toInteger(s)]
```

Comment: Thank you - If I understand the above correctly it is creating an array, splitting the array in the csv and then adding the values as integers into the new array? Unfortunately I can't get it to work as I'm getting this error: Type mismatch: accumulator is List<T> but expression has type Integer

Comment: added an example

Comment: Awesome, thank you that works. Just need to ignore null values and I’m done!

Comment: @Sean it could even be shorter :)  see additional solution